No module named 'torch.utils'
Friends, I am programming on the Phytec board. I am trying to run the program code using Ultralytics. I install the libraries locally, that is, in the root of the system. It cannot load the libraries.
Error code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/test_2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ultralytics import YOLO
  File "/root/Ultralytics/ultralytics/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ultralytics.data.explorer.explorer import Explorer
  File "/root/Ultralytics/ultralytics/data/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .base import BaseDataset
  File "/root/Ultralytics/ultralytics/data/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data import Dataset
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils'

Part of the code:
import cv2
import time
import sys
sys.path.append('/root/Ultralytics')
from ultralytics import YOLO
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
# Reading a video file
vid = cv2.VideoCapture('/media/andrei/Linux_dir/Analytics/YoloNew/p.mp4')

# Loading the YOLOv8n model
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")

# Specifying the "person" class
person_class_index = 0 # The 'person' class in the COCO dataset has ID = 0

# Initializing variables for frame and time
f = 0
t = 0
h, w = None, None
writer = None

....

I tried to install Torch.Utils separately, it didn't help

First you need to install torch :
for CPU
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio

then:
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset


if you want to use ultralytics you can do:
from ultralytics.data.dataset import Dataset

